# How to redirect from facebook to my application through app link share

Tags: ios, facebook, deep-linking

I have added scheme in my app. myapp://

I have shared an article from website of the app called www.myapp.com/post/123

I wanted to open the app from shared URL as i follow all meta tag required by facebook.

[Facebook meta tag instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content)

```
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapp://" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="12345" />
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Example App" />
<meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

On tapping shared post, its redirect to webview of facebook. i have a button called OPEN APP. by tapping its not opening the app.

What step am i missing?

**By hitting that scheme [myapp://] on safari its redirecting to the app**

Comment: Have you confirmed that the URI scheme opens your app outside of Facebook?

Comment: @clayjones94 Yes, Through safari i have check its working. As APP to APP redirection requires scheme of other app. i don't know how facebook doing it. but i have seen its working with big platform like medium